# ANTLR: bug in setUnknownTokenBoundaries()?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

[CommonTree#setUnknownTokenBoundaries()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5/org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree.java#CommonTree.setUnknownTokenBoundaries%28%29)  updates token boundaries of an AST node by using the boundaries of the node's first and last child.  This seems to assume that the children of the AST are ordered by the token order.  However, such an ordering is not enforced when constructing ASTs.

Is this a bug?  Should setUnknownTokenBoundaries() be updated to pick the min/max among all of the children instead of just using the first and last child?  Or am I missing something...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should probably be posted here instead: https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/issues

Comment: OK. https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/issues/103